# How To: semantic-ui-react drop down passing drop-down selection to other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have a parent component (`App`) that is using two child components `Chart` and `Artists`.

The `Artists` component is a drop-down created with the `semantic-ui-react` library.

What I'm trying to do is make the drop-down into its own component (`Artists`) that, when changed, will change the `artist` state in the parent component (`App`) and then that `artist` state in `App` can be passed as an `artist` prop to the `Chart` component

Everything is working so far it's just that the drop down looks strange (options are outside of the drop-down box: picture below). I'm not sure if I'm setting this up the right way.

[image]

**App component:**

```
import './App.css';
import Chart from './Chart.js';
import {useState} from 'react';
import Artists from './Artists.js';

const artistOptions = [
  {
    text: 'Bruno Mars',
    value: 'Bruno Mars'
  },
  {
    text: 'Billie Eilish',
    value: 'Billie Eilish'
  }
  ...
]

export default function App() {

  const [artist, setArtist] = useState('Bruno Mars');

  const handleArtistChange = (artist) => {
    setArtist(artist);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Awards for {artist}</h2>
      <Artists options={artistOptions} onArtistChange={handleArtistChange}/>
      <Chart data={data} height={150} width={960} show={"Grammys"} artist={artist} />
    </div>
  );

}
```

**Artists component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Dropdown} from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default function Artists (props) {

    const handleOnChange = (e, data) => {
        props.onArtistChange(data.value);
    }

    return(
        <Dropdown placeholder='placeholder' search selection options={props.options} onChange={handleOnChange} />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

This problem occured because you apparently haven't add CSS to HTML styles yet.

Add:

> https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui/dist/semantic.min.css

as an stylesheet to your react index.html.

#### Sandbox:

Here's a sandbox to help you better:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-example-forked-mv3bv?file=/index.js